# readFileSync returns no data even though file exists

Tags: node.js, macos, filesystems

tl;dr

readFileSync returns a zero sized result after reading a file that is ~24kb. No errors are thrown.

The not so tl;dr

To start of, I use browserify programatically to build three JS files. This completes successfully, the files are present at the location I expected, file names are what I expect, manually checking the file size and contents all is as expected.

A little later during code execution I use `readFileSync` to read these files back in, and concatenate them with other files to create bundles. Problem is, for one of the three generated files, all is good, but for the other two, `readFileSync` always returns a zero length result.

Again, the files definitely contain data.

Running `fs.statSync` on the file indeed shows the size to be 0 :-/ For example, here are the stats for one of the files:

```
Stats {
  dev: 16777220,
  mode: 33188,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 501,
  gid: 20,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: 4194304,
  ino: 10106323,
  size: 0,
  blocks: 0,
  atimeMs: 1536239893064.3716,
  mtimeMs: 1536239915850.5076,
  ctimeMs: 1536239915850.5076,
  birthtimeMs: 1536239886797.752,
  atime: 2018-09-06T13:18:13.064Z,
  mtime: 2018-09-06T13:18:35.851Z,
  ctime: 2018-09-06T13:18:35.851Z,
  birthtime: 2018-09-06T13:18:06.798Z 
}
```

For the life of me I cannot figure out why Node/OS seems to think that these files are empty. Has anyone run into this situation before? Apologies if the question is to broad.

UPDATE: Turns out all three the files built with browserify behaves the same. The one just seemed to work because it was bundling another JS file. When I ran the code over it alone, I also get no data returned.

Here is the code the generates the files with browserify:

```
const entryFiles = config.editorBundles.split(',');

for (let file in entryFiles) {
  let currentFile = entryFiles[file];
  let outputBaseFileName = currentFile.substr(
    0,
    currentFile.indexOf('.js')
  );
  let writableOutputFile = fs.createWriteStream(
      path.join(__dirname, `${outputBaseFileName}-bundle.js`)
  );

try {
    let brfy = browserify(
        path.join(__dirname, entryFiles[file])
    ).bundle();
    brfy.pipe(writableOutputFile);
} catch (error) {
    console.error('MDN-BOB: (bundler.js/@compileJS)', error);
    reject(
        Error(
            'MDN-BOB: (bundler.js/@compileJS) Error while bundling and writing'
        )
    );
}
```

I am wondering whether the way this(`brfy.pipe(writableOutputFile);`) writes to the file is causing the problem?

Comment: Forgot to mention, I also checked whether the file exists and is readable using `fs.access`. Both checks returned true...

Comment: Will you show where `readFileSync` is called in the code? Piping into a writable stream is async, so it is possible that you are trying to read the file before enough data makes it through the pipe

Comment: @dpopp07 That is what I was thinking after looking at the code more. It smells a lot like a race condition. I have refactor the code to wrap each write instance inside a Promise that is resolved once the `ReadStream` emits the `end` event. I then pass all those promises to `Promise.all` and once it calls back, I call the remaining work. Now it works \o/

Answer (score 0):

After thinking some more, looking over the code, and the super helpful comment from @dpopp07(`.pipe` is async), I realised what was going on here is a race condition. At the point where the read was happening, the write was very likely to not have finished.

That being the case, I had to refactor how the flow of the work happened. Each piece of work was already wrapped in a `Promise` but, seeing that there was some async work happening this did not solve the problem(clearly ;)).

I therefore changed the `for` loop from before into the following functi:

```
function processAndWrite() {
    const entryFiles = config.editorBundles.split(',');
    let filePromises = [];

    for (let file in entryFiles) {
        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let currentFile = entryFiles[file];
            let outputBaseFileName = currentFile.substr(
                0,
                currentFile.indexOf('.js')
            );
            let outputFilename = `${outputBaseFileName}-bundle.js`;
            let writableOutputFile = fs.createWriteStream(
                path.join(__dirname, outputFilename)
            );

            try {
                let reader = browserify(
                    path.join(__dirname, entryFiles[file])
                ).bundle();
                let writer = reader.pipe(writableOutputFile);
                reader.on('end', () => {
                    resolve(`${outputFilename} written to disk`);
                });
            } catch (error) {
                reject(
                    Error('MDN-BOB: (bundler.js/@compileJS) Error compiling JS')
                );
            }
        });
        filePromises.push(promise);
    }
    return filePromises;
}
```

I then use `Promise.all` passing in the array of `filePromises`. Once all those promises completes, I then resume with the rest of the program. This ensures that the files are definitely done writing before they are read later. w00t